# Preferred communicator for teaching music online

Tags: software

Please, bear with me if this is a wrong place to ask about this.

Due to recent COVID epidemic my girlfriend has switched from teaching music in a school to teaching online. She calls students via Skype or Facebook messenger. It looks like those communicators are optimized towards talking. However, when a student starts to sing one of the following problems occurs:

- the quality of the sound deteriorates or the sound is broken
- the sound arrives with a significant delay which hardens singing in sync with piano accompaniment.

Is there any communicator that is better suited for teaching music remotely?

Comment: You can try [Zoom](https://zoom.us/)

Answer (score 1):

I've been teaching guitar online for the last two weeks to about 50 students, and I've used different systems, because it turned out that there's no single system that works in practice for all students. However, I mainly use browser based systems, and on average they work fine.

I've also encountered the first problem you describe, namely the deterioration of any sound other than speech. This has nothing to do with the system you use. It can happen on skype or anywhere else. It has to do with the device on the other end of the communication link. Some devices try to detect speech and suppress anything else, which they classify as noise. Depending on the system, there may be an audio setting that allows you to switch off that "optimize for speech" setting, but how and if it is possible at all depends on the system, the drivers, etc. In general, unless the student is handy with computers, you're out of luck in such a situation. Now, this only happens when the student uses the built-in mic (or a mic directly connected to the computer via the analog audio input). If you can convince the student to use a USB-mic or to connect a mic via an audio interface the problem will be solved.

As for delay/latency, that's inherent to internet communication, and you can't get rid of it. As far as I know, there is no simple way to actually play/sing together in such a setting. Of course, the teacher can play an accompaniment and the student can play/sing along, but the teacher won't be able to hear if the student's timing is correct. One way to fix that is to send a recording to the student, have the student play it back during the lesson while she/he sings/plays along. In that case it's possible to judge timing and phrasing because both sounds are fed back in sync via the student's mic.